# Writing a small Windows script to talk to the mainframe and/or Endevor

Tags: windows, protocols, mainframe, zos

I am trying to optimize my work process in my day to day life as an it developer in a larger bank. Right now, all development is done using Rational Developer for System Z (RDz), working with files on the Endevor reposity, and there are several issues with this solution that I would like to develop a work-around for in my spare time.

Right now I am very much in the blind about how communication with the mainframe and Endevor is done from a PC. As I can see, it is possible to do so, since RDz does exactly that.

What I really need may not be so complex. I need to understand how clients like RDz or Personal Communications are able to communicate with the mainframe. Alternatively, I could try and generate some sort of script to retrieve files from Endevor on the host, since I am able to FTP to an MVS and get files that way. But I have no way of FTP'ing to an Endevor repository.

Basically I would like a way to get files from Endevor and on to my desktop, so I can edit them there in my favorite text editor, and then a way to put them back again.

Any suggestions as to how I should get started on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the basic building blocks for your desktop script:

- Build a file containing JCL to extract target source code from Endevor into a staging PDS. You need
  to parameterize the JCL build process to accommodate different source file designations.
- Submit the JCL to run on the mainframe using FTP (Filetype=JES)
- Wait for the job to complete (watch the FTP log file)
- Use FTP (Filetype=SEQ) to retrieve the file from the mainframe staging PDS to your desktop
- Edit on desktop using your favourite editor

When done, just reverse the process.

Technically this is not a difficult process to build. The potential glitch is that you
probably do not have the authority to submit high priority batch jobs. If your submitted
batch job ends up queued for a couple of minutes (hours) then this process becomes
unworkable. If you can submit high priority batch jobs, then
the rest should not be all that difficult. I have done something very similar to
this using [Open Object Rexx](http://www.oorexx.org/) as the desktop scripting language - and it works very
well.

You can get a pretty good idea as to what the JCL needs to look like by using the Endevor: Build batch SCL
option to construct example JCL for extract/check-in functions. Interacting with JES trough FTP is described pretty well in: 
[Interfacing with JES](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/F1A1B960/4.13?DT=20060622162500).

Have fun...

Comment: I keep forgetting that some shops allow one to submit jobs via FTP.  Mine doesn't.  Security.

Comment: Hi NealB, and thanks for your comments. I understand most of it, though as cschneid says, I am unsure as to submit a JCL using FTP. I will read up on the link you gave me. :-)

I do however understand the retrieve syntax for the JCL script for Endevor. I have been looking around to make a Rexx script that I could execute on the mainframe by somehow writing a small script that could log on the mainframe and then interact with it without using Personal Communications. But I think your solution sounds easier to do, since I am not sure how the mainframe protocol is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Endevor documentation to see if it has an API, or a web services interface.  Change Man (a competing product) does, I would expect Endevor to have one too.

Directly FTPing into a source code management systems's repository is not likely something you'd want to do.  You'd want to check things out and check them in, *using* the product rather than trying to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is C-Cubed, www.c-cubed.net.  They offer API's that allow various Windows PC languages to interface directly with Endevor, and other products.  We utilize it at my current workplace to access MVS resources on 50 different LPAR's.
Hope it helps.